# I am not able to execute the following aws cli command

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to execute the below command but I am getting an error can anyone please help

```
 aws --profile awsprofile logs  put-log-events --log-group-name mylogs --log-stream-name 20150601 --log-events file:///var/log/kafka/server.log.2016-09-25-02
```

Error:-

```
Expecting ',' delimiter or ']': line 1 column 6 (char 5)
```

So I determine the problem is with file:///

I want to specify /var/log/kafka/server.log.2016-09-25-02

as when I specify var/log/kafka/server.log.2016-09-25-02 it is saying file not found so I want to specify /var/log/kafka/server.log.2016-09-25-02. But when I specify in that way it is showing error as

```
Expecting ',' delimiter or ']': line 1 column 6 (char 5)
```

So please help me. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: it should work with `file:///var/log/kafka/server.log.2016-09-25-02` for simple test just move the file somewhere on relative path and retry, I guess you'll face the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the CLI command line, but in your log_events file `/var/log/kafka/server.log.2016-09-25-02`. It is not a valid JSON file.

Take a look at: [put-log-event example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-log-events.html#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Put " or ' around file:///var/log/kafka/server.log.2016-09-25-02

Comment: Even after keeping them it's not working   aws --profile awsprofile logs  put-log-events --log-group-name mylogs --log-stream-name 20150601 --log-events "file:///var/log/kafka/server.log.2016-09-25-02"

Expecting ',' delimiter or ']': line 1 column 6 (char 5)